# Is it legal to display user airline seat info on a public platform with absolute user consent

Tags: software, gdpr, regulations

Planning a public platform to display user seating info after taking proper user consent , will that still attract legalities if user is ok with it , will it fall under any legal clauses under GDPR regulations.

Comment: If you fulfill the Art 7 conditions for consent this should be fine, although you will still have to comply with all GDPR requirements (information, access, erasure, etc). Could you explain a bit more for which *purpose* the seating info should be published? Will you obtain the data from users or third parties?

Comment: What do you mean by "user seating info"?

Comment: the passenger name and the seat number where he/she will be sitting will be displayed if the user is willing .

Answer (score 2):

Consent is necessary but not sufficient. You must still obey by the other GDPR rules as well. If the user changes his or her mind, for instance, you must remove the data.